# Are questions "Is X faithful to the books/comics/...?" suitable/good questions for this site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Many questions here and on the very related Movies and TV sites are about adaptations of books or comics. For example, questions about Sherlock Holmes adaptations (*Sherlock*, *Elementary* or the Guy Pierce movies) or about *Harry Potter* are quite popular. Also, many comics had been adapted to movies or TV in the recent years.

My question: Is it suitable to ask a question about how faithful to its original source an adaptation is?

On the pros:

1. Often, the first comments to many of the questions mentioned above are "Are you speaking about the movie?" or "Do you speak about the comics?". Sometimes, tags help but it could be good to have a question to clarify the situation.

On the cons:

1. Maybe opinion-based, depending on what people think is the core ideas of the original material.
2. An answer to this question may turn into a list of all the tiny (and probably worthless) details that differ between mediums. E.g "In the book, A has light grey eyes whereas [actor potraying A] has blue eyes!"
3. Such questions could be "Does it worth looking at the movie/TV shows" in disguise. If it is well disguised, it is not a problem. But it could attract totally opinion-based answers like "The movie sucks. Read the book!".

PS: I didn't know how to tag this question. Feel free to improve it!

Comment: **Yes**. And there is also precedent. See Game of Thrones etc. Unfortunately though, this meta question already has an answer [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2515/what-to-do-with-adaptation-differences-questions) (I think).